# Finding a difference in counts - Microsoft Access & SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

So I have two tables, each with a few thousand records. Only two fields - ID and Count of ID.

The tables should have approximately 30 of these IDs which have differing counts. I'm trying to locate them by running a query to pull out the mismatches on count.

```
ID|Count
A | 5
B | 12
C | 9

A | 5
B | 13
C | 9
```

In the above case I would want to pull only record B, so I can flag it as being a mismatch. I'm not sure of an easy way to do that. I've tried Outer Join (Union All in Access), left and right joins on both fields. Nothing is working.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh Sorry! I removed the tag. I'm using MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward if I understand the question (your tables are already aggregated and ID in both is a PK). Just need a `WHERE` clause to return counts that do not match per ID.

```
SELECT b.ID, b.[CountOfID]
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.[CountOfID] <> b.[CountOfID]
```

This assumes that any existing ID in the first table also exists in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to get id with different counts (I called count column as count_col as count is reserved keyword).

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having count(distinct count_col) > 1;
```

If you want to find all the rows with these ids, you can use `IN`:

```
select *
from your_table
where id in (
    select id
    from your_table
    group by id
    having count(distinct count_col) > 1
);
```